# Difference between Homomorphism and Isomorphism for prove of Group properties

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

If I have the following:

$N := \{(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{Z}^4 \mid ad-bc = 1\}$

$(a,b,c,d) \circ (e,f,g,h) := (ae+bg,af+bh,ce+dg,cf+dh)$

The task is: Check $(N, \circ)$ for Group properties

I've found an Isomorphism to the following:

$M := \{A\in M(2,2) \mid \det(A) = 1\}$

with the standard matrix-product.

Let $f:N \to M$ with $(a,b,c,d) \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$

$f$ is bijective, which is fairly obvious.

I've shown that $f$ does indeed keep the properties needed for an isomorphism, since that is not the point, I'll leave that out.

Now we know that

$(M,*)$ is a non-abelian group, so $(N,\circ)$ is also a non-abelian group.

Now that's straight forward, the question that came up was, can we prove the same without a bijective mapping and if not, why?

To make clear what I mean: Would a homomorphism between $N$ and $M$ prove the same thing?

Comment: Suppose you took the trivial homomorphism $\phi(a,b,c,d)=1$. That would not help!

Comment: @almagest Would $\phi(a,b,c,d) = 1$ satisfy $\phi((a,b,c,d)\circ(e,f,g,h)) = \phi(a,b,c,d) \phi(e,f,g,h)$?

Comment: Why not? $1\times 1=1$.

Comment: I won't speak about homomorphisms in general, but you should be more explicit about $M(2, 2)$. In particular... does $\pmatrix{2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 }$ have an inverse in $M$?

Comment: @pjs36 I see what you mean, using M twice wasn't smart, but if we ignore that, $M$ clearly only holds elements of $M(2,2)$ where $\det(A) = 1$, thus the inverse exists.

Comment: I don't mean $M$ being slightly overloaded, I mean that it matters where we get our entries in a matrix. There are lots of different "collections" of $2 \times 2$ matrices; the matrix above has an inverse in some, not in others. But, I actually forgot that it doesn't make a difference in this case.

Comment: I think you need to take care about how you express this: usually we define homomorphisms and isomorphisms between groups, and of course at the outset you don't know $N$ is a group, so techinically the notion of "isomorphism" makes no sense. You can work around this, but as I say it needs a bit of care!

Answer (score 1):

A homomorphism alone would not be enough, as was already discussed in the comments. But perhaps even more important is to know natural examples of groups; and here the group of integral matrices with determinant $1$, $M=SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is much more natural than $N$, although they are of course isomorphic. So it really makes sense to *use* the bijection, and to understand its value. Closely related to $M$ is the [modular group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group), which arises in several contexts of mathematics and physics.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit on why a homomorphism alone won't work? That's the real point I fail to understand. The only way I've been able to explain it to myself is that if $f$ is bijective, we can calculate whatever we want in the known group and use the inverse $f^{-1}$ to return back to our original set/group.

Comment: As I said, it was already answered in the comments. A homomorphism $f:N\rightarrow M$ might not give any non-trivial property about $M$. Take the trivial homomorphism $f$, mapping everything to the matrix $I_2$ in $M$. So we only have then the identity matrix $I_2$, i.,e., the image is the trivial group.